# App to hand write notes

Tags: applications, notes

I am looking for an app that would be good for taking hand written notes on a 10 inch screen tablet
The closest app that i found is "note everything"  What makes it short of my requirements is

1(most important) Drawn notes that i can write on are each 1 tablet screen size.  I want something that can be scrolled down forever as i need more space.  Something the way a normal document works.  At worst it should let me instantly page another full canvas forward, not have to create a new note for every page
2. text notes and hand written notes are separated into separate files.  I would like the whole note to be hand written, but be able to add typed ares
3. There are no lines in the paint section.  Makes it hard to write

Can anyone suggest anything better?

Answer (score 1):

[Quick notes](http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/productivity/quick-notes_krwo.html) is alright.

Comment: This app only allows one page per note.